# Is it possible that two different classes have a property -a collection of classes and each object knows which of the first two classes it belongs to?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I have next 3 classes

```
class Review
{
   public int Id{get; set;}
   public string Text{get; set;}
   public ICollection<Comment> Comments{get; set;}
//some additional properties
}
class User
{
   public int Id{get; set;}
   public string Name{get; set;}
   public string Login{get; set;}
   public ICollection<Comment> Comments{get; set;}
//some additional properties
}
class Comment
{
   public int Id{get; set}
   public string Comment{get; set;}
   public ??? Target{get; set;}
}
```

In this context, a Target is what the comment was attached to. And for some things, I need to know exactly who the target is - a specific user or a specific review.
And inheriting from the interface is not suitable due to the strong distinction in the parameters. And i need to use database so object type not for that kind of situation(as i know).

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind to actually work is to use string like "U123", where first char - what type i use and so all classes have Id, 123 - id. But its seems to me that there better way to solve that. If I don’t find another answer, I’ll use this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code provided you can use `object` or `dynamic` for `Target`.

But you may prefer using a base class for `Review` and `User` like `BaseObjectWithComments` to be able to write `BaseObjectWithComments Target`, which is a little better.

So we can move some members to this root class.

Also we can add a constructor for `Comment` to pass the owner.

```
public abstract class BaseObjectWithIdAndComments
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Review : BaseObjectWithIdAndComments
{
  public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class User : BaseObjectWithIdAndComments
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Login { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public BaseObjectWithIdAndComments Target { get; set; }
  public Comment(BaseObjectWithIdAndComments owner, int id, string comment)
  {
    Target = owner;
    ID = id;
    Text = comment;
  }
}
```

*Test*

```
var review = new Review();
var user = new User();

review.Comments = new List<Comment>();
user.Comments = new List<Comment>();

review.Comments.Add(new Comment(review, 1, "review comment 1"));
review.Comments.Add(new Comment(review, 2, "review comment 2"));

user.Comments.Add(new Comment(user, 1, "user comment 1"));
user.Comments.Add(new Comment(user, 2, "user comment 2"));

Console.WriteLine("Owner of review comment #1: " + review.Comments.ElementAt(0).Target.GetType().Name);
Console.WriteLine("Owner of user comment #2: " + user.Comments.ElementAt(1).Target.GetType().Name);
```

*Output*

```html
Owner of review comment #1: Review
Owner of user comment #2: User
```

**About using a database, you need to change the design.**

For example the fields of the table may be like:

```html
CommentID
ReviewID
UserID
Text
```

But this is not clean, so you may prefer to have 2 tables to be more conventionnal: `UserComments` and `ReviewComments`, thus each of these tables will have a `OwnerID` pointing to `Users` or `Reviews`.

Thus you can load data in the instances of the previous classes while setting the owner reference as indicated.

[image]

*Maybe you can consider using an ADO.NET typed DataSet that does all the work for you while being able to use Visual Studio RAD Designers*:

[Typed DataSets (MS Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/typed-datasets)

[How to: Create and configure datasets in Visual Studio (MS Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/data-tools/create-and-configure-datasets-in-visual-studio)

[Beginning C# 2005 Databases (Wrox)](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Beginning+C%23+2005+Databases-p-9780470044063)